# When running phpdoc on a CodeIgniter project, which folders should be included?

Tags: codeigniter, directory, phpdoc

On my first try, I've only included system/application/models, system/application/controllers, system/application/helpers, and system/application/libraries.  I chose those folders because I think those folders contain the code that you want to be properly documented for future reference. What other folders do you think should be included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be thorough in terms of your own code. I would recommend the following folders and where necessary have annotated:

1. **system/application/controllers**
2. **system/application/helpers**
3. **system/application/hooks** - Don't miss this out! Any time that you change/extend the CI core, you should definitely document it
4. **system/application/models**
5. **system/application/libraries**
6. **system/application/language** - This may come in useful when implementing localisation
7. **system/plugins** - As you're including libraries, it would make sense to include any external plug-ins being used as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it covered. The rest is probably documented in CodeIgniter's documentation already.

If you add any plugin/library/whatever that requires to be outside of these folders, make sure you add them later as well.